# lotus notes crashing when swing dialogbox appears

Tags: swing, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I coded an agent in Java that displays some text using JDialogBox. Now for one of the many users of that application it is not working. whenever the user clicks on action that initiates that agent, a dialogbox appears but before it could display completely notes crashes, giving the error message that Notes rtying to collect information..and so on..

Now if there is no other solution for this problem, then i would like to know if there is any way in which i can call the default NOTES @prompt or MsgBox from Java agent, to diaplay value. The value to be displayed is calculated by that agent on the fly and is not stored on the form.

```
############################################################
### FATAL THREAD 23/24 [ nlnotes: 4124: 4652]
### FP=0x000186a0, PC=0x69b824fb, SP=0x0bedff6c, stksize=-200046796
### EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x0a7a8390, ECX=0x0a7a8390, EDX=0x0a7a8390
### ESI=0x0a2a0e40, EDI=0x00000000, CS=0x0000001b, SS=0x00000023
### DS=0x00000023, ES=0x00000023, FS=0x0000003b, GS=0x00000000 Flags=0x00010206
Exception code: c0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)
############################################################
 [ 1] 0x69b824fb nvoglnt

############################################################
### PASS 2 : FATAL THREAD with STACK FRAMES 23/24 [ nlnotes: 4124: 4652]
### FP=000186a0, PC=69b824fb, SP=0bedff6c, stksize=-200046796
Exception code: c0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)
############################################################
# ---------- Top of the Stack ----------
 [ 1] 0x69b824fb nvoglnt

############################################################
### PASS 3 : FATAL THREAD with PARAMETER DATA 23/24 [ nlnotes: 4124: 4652]
############################################################
 [ 1] 0x69b824fb nvoglnt

############################################################
### thread 24/24: [ nlnotes: 4124: 5516] 
### FP=0bcffff4, PC=7c90120f, SP=0bcfffcc, stkbase=0bcf0000, stksize=4096
############################################################
@[ 1] 0x7c90120f ntdll.DbgBreakPoint+1 (0,0,0,0)


<@@ Notes Process Info -> Load Modules for Process: [ntaskldr: 5404] (Time 10:18:19) @@>

Base        Size          Module

0x00400000       20480  C:\notes\ntaskldr.EXE
0x7c900000      729088  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000     1007616  C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
0x6ef90000      454656  C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SYSFER.DLL
0x60000000    14053376  C:\notes\nnotes.dll
0x621b0000     1400832  C:\notes\nxmlpar.dll
0x62320000       98304  C:\notes\nxmlcommon.dll
0x77c10000      360448  C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x62150000      380928  C:\notes\js32.dll
0x62350000      999424  C:\notes\NLSCCSTR.DLL
0x77dd0000      634880  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000      602112  C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000       69632  C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x76780000       36864  c:\windows\system32\SHFOLDER.dll
0x77120000      569344  C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x77f10000      299008  C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x7e410000      593920  C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x774e0000     1302528  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x763b0000      299008  C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x5d090000      630784  C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.dll
0x7c9c0000     8482816  C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x77f60000      483328  C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x71ad0000       36864  C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsock32.dll
0x71ab0000       94208  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000       32768  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x62950000       24576  C:\notes\ndgts.dll
0x76390000      118784  C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x773d0000     1060864  C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\comctl32.dll
0x624d0000      897024  C:\notes\NSTRINGS.DLL
0x62890000       24576  C:\notes\nhkdaemn.DLL
0x62930000       24576  C:\notes\nhldaemn.DLL
0x625b0000       24576  C:\notes\namhook.DLL
0x625d0000       36864  C:\notes\nTCP.DLL

<@@ Notes Process Info -> Call Stack for Process: [ntaskldr: 5404] (Time 10:18:19) @@>

############################################################
### thread 1/4: [ntaskldr: 5404: 5816] 
### FP=0013fc44, PC=7c90e514, SP=0013fbec, stkbase=00040000, stksize=28672
############################################################
@[ 1] 0x7c90e514 ntdll.KiFastSystemCallRet+0 (1388,0,13fc60,600a2d5d)
@[ 2] 0x7c802455 KERNEL32.Sleep+15 (1388,13fc80,60003e17,1388)
@[ 3] 0x600a2d5d nnotes._OSDelayThread@4+13 (1388)
@[ 4] 0x60003e17 nnotes._OSStaticMem@8+231 (0,8132)
@[ 5] 0x6000f1c2 nnotes._OSStaticMemBeginInit@16+98 (0,8132,696,13fdd0)
@[ 6] 0x601d4159 nnotes._NotesSDKData@0+25 ()
@[ 7] 0x601d45d5 nnotes._AddInShouldTerminate@0+5 ()
@[ 8] 0x601d45fa nnotes._AddInIdle@0+10 ()
@[ 9] 0x00401816 ntaskldr._notes_main+214 (0,0,0,2)
@[10] 0x00401736 ntaskldr._main+22 (2,383f98,382d00,403000)
@[11] 0x00401ae3 ntaskldr._mainCRTStartup+227 (39588,13d1d8,7ffde000,8054b6ed)
@[12] 0x7c817077 KERNEL32.RegisterWaitForInputIdle+73 (401a00,0,0,0)

############################################################
### thread 2/4: [ntaskldr: 5404: 5284] 
### FP=02dcfcc8, PC=7c90e514, SP=02dcfc70, stkbase=02cd0000, stksize=262144
############################################################
@[ 1] 0x7c90e514 ntdll.KiFastSystemCallRet+0 (1388,0,2dcfce4,600a2d5d)
@[ 2] 0x7c802455 KERNEL32.Sleep+15 (1388,2dcfd04,60003e17,1388)
@[ 3] 0x600a2d5d nnotes._OSDelayThread@4+13 (1388)
@[ 4] 0x60003e17 nnotes._OSStaticMem@8+231 (0,8132)
@[ 5] 0x6000f1c2 nnotes._OSStaticMemBeginInit@16+98 (0,8132,696,2dcfe54)
@[ 6] 0x601d4159 nnotes._NotesSDKData@0+25 ()
@[ 7] 0x601d45d5 nnotes._AddInShouldTerminate@0+5 ()
@[ 8] 0x601d45fa nnotes._AddInIdle@0+10 ()
@[ 9] 0x00401011 ntaskldr.EntryFuncWrapper+17 (1e13514,0,0,7c912228)
@[10] 0x60116d74 nnotes._ThreadWrapper@4+212 (0)
@[11] 0x7c80b729 KERNEL32.GetModuleFileNameA+442 (0,0,0,0)

############################################################
### thread 3/4: [ntaskldr: 5404: 1796] 
### FP=02ecfcb4, PC=7c90e514, SP=02ecfc5c, stkbase=02dd0000, stksize=262144
############################################################
@[ 1] 0x7c90e514 ntdll.KiFastSystemCallRet+0 (1388,0,2ecfcd0,600a2d5d)
@[ 2] 0x7c802455 KERNEL32.Sleep+15 (1388,2ecfcf0,60003e17,1388)
@[ 3] 0x600a2d5d nnotes._OSDelayThread@4+13 (1388)
@[ 4] 0x60003e17 nnotes._OSStaticMem@8+231 (0,8132)
@[ 5] 0x6000f1c2 nnotes._OSStaticMemBeginInit@16+98 (0,8132,696,2ecfe40)
@[ 6] 0x601d4159 nnotes._NotesSDKData@0+25 ()
@[ 7] 0x601d45d5 nnotes._AddInShouldTerminate@0+5 ()
@[ 8] 0x601d45fa nnotes._AddInIdle@0+10 ()
@[ 9] 0x00401011 ntaskldr.EntryFuncWrapper+17 (1e13614,0,0,7c912228)
@[10] 0x60116d74 nnotes._ThreadWrapper@4+212 (0)
@[11] 0x7c80b729 KERNEL32.GetModuleFileNameA+442 (60116ca0,0,0,dddd04d2)

############################################################
### thread 4/4: [ntaskldr: 5404: 3296] 
### FP=032dfff4, PC=7c90120f, SP=032dffcc, stkbase=032d0000, stksize=4096
############################################################
@[ 1] 0x7c90120f ntdll.DbgBreakPoint+1 (0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: I tried deleting the notes cache and bookmark.nsf on users machine but that also did not worked.

Comment: Open the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder and then open the NSD created by the crash. Have a look for FATAL and add the fatal stack to your post.

Comment: Well this is my next step..already onto it

Comment: nvoglnt is NVidia graphics driver. You could try updating your graphics drivers to see if that helps. If not, it is possible the JVM can't support NVidia drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDialog is part of AWT and that will not work in R8.x (nor supported).

[edit] Based on your update of the NSD.

nvoglnt is NVidia graphics driver. You could try updating your graphics drivers to see if that helps. If not, it is possible the JVM can't support the latest NVidia drivers.

Comment: Just to add, you can use SWT instead but there is a known redraw issue in relation to Agents. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO56885

Comment: I am using LN 6.5..that shld support AWT..both are contemporary

Comment: Yep that should work for that version. So will need NSD fatal stack to take any further guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call any UI methods in Notes from a Java Agent, unfortunately.  If you have a Java based solution working I'd pursue that and try to fix the problem on that users's machine